# Cant run ECS external task

Tags: amazon-ecs

I have an EC2 ubuntu machine (g5.large). I registered the machine as an external instance on ECS.
I created Task definition, cluster, etc...
Did a couple of testing runs and everything went fine.

Than I created new cluster with new EC2 (same configs and settings as above) and suddenly  I can't run any task definition.

I get this error:
CgroupError: Agent could not create task's platform resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

```
echo "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=false" | sudo tee /etc/default/grub.d/cgroup.cfg
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Could you share some context? Why did it fail and how this fixes the problem?